# existence of simple sub-quotient for general module over a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Is it true that a general non-trivial module over a general ring always has a simple sub-quotient?
In other words is the Jordan-Holder content of a non-trivial module always non-empty?

If not what is a counter example?

Answer (score 0):

Any non-trivial module $M$ over a (unitary) ring $R$ admits a simple sub-quotient.  To see this, let $x\in M$ be a non-zero element, and let $Rx$ be the submodule generated by $x$.  Then $Rx$ is a finitely-generated module, and it follows from [Krull's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_theorem) that it admits a maximal submodule $N$.  Then $Rx/N$ is a simple sub-quotient of $M$.